# THREE.loadTexture() cause flashing in setInterval() update

Tags: three.js

Im looking to frequently update a materials texture with an image source in three js.

I can do this by calling the following in my init()

```
setInterval(function(){
  var pullImg = $('#frame_loader').attr('src');
  var tmp = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(pullImg);
  planeMesh.material.map = tmp;
  planeMesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
},100);
```

However, this results in a lot of flashiness.

I theorize that having this asynchronous to the render loop is the culprit.

However, when I attempt to migrate the above contents of setInterval() to render(), the texture is not applied. `planeMesh` remains black.

How might I get rid of this flashing?

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh, I wasnt waiting for the texture to load.

Stick the material update into an anonymous callback in loadTexture() and the flash/flicker stops

```
THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(pullImg,{},function(){
  planeMesh.material.map = tmp;
  planeMesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
});
```